# ASP.NET AJAX PageMethods call load whole page for .NET 4.5 IIS 7.5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, pagemethods

I am calling pageMethod in codebehind of aspx page. I get the response for whole page instead of webMethod response. Also, I tried calling the same webMethod using jquery and got the whole page as response.

```
Client:

  <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="True"
 EnablePageMethods="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true" >

function TestNumber() {
PageMethods.getNumber(ResponseTest);
}

 function ResponseTest(response){
          var num = response.d;
      }

CodeBehind:

 [WebMethod]  
 public static int getNumber()
        {
            return accountNumber;
        }
```

I am using .NET 4.5.1 and IIS7.5 and I think the issue is realted to in built extensionless URLS  in VS2013. I am using the following web.config sys.webserver

```
  <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ScriptModule" />
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </modules>
        <handlers>
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
          <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
          <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
```

I tried the same through Jquery ajax call and got whole page. Am i missing any thing?

Comment: can any one please share correct sys.webserver configuration for AJAX page method or jquery ajax call approaches, considering the default extensionless entries in IIS7+. I am using .NET 4.5.1. thanks.

Comment: So did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 4):

Friendly URLs (the extensionless URL library that's part of the default project template) doesn't support invocation of [WebMethod] routines.  If you must use [WebMethod], uninstall Friendly URLs from the project.  This can be done from the [Nuget Package Manager window](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/Managing-NuGet-Packages-Using-The-Dialog#Removing_a_Package).

Once you remove this package, you may need to fix links in your project and in your Web.config file to add back the missing .aspx extensions.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using friendly urls, then add

```
PageMethods.set_path(PageMethods.get_path() + '.aspx');
```

to your js

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

yes, it seems to be web.config setting.

try removing this line from `<modules>` section `<remove name="ScriptModule" />`

just add

```
<system.webServer>
 <modules>
   <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
 </modules>
</system.webServer>
```